# SGDClassifier accuracy MUCH worse than LinearSVC

Tags: scikit-learn, online-learning

with LinearSVC, I get an accuracy off 0.89:

```
linearSVC = LinearSVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = linearSVC.predict(X_test)
print('accuracy', np.sum(y_pred == y_test) / y_test.shape[0])
```

Because I need online training, I tried the same with SGDClassifier:

```
sgd = SGDClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = sgd.predict(X_test)
print('accuracy', np.sum(y_pred == y_test) / y_test.shape[0])
```

but now I get 0.004 - what am I missing here? The shape of X_train is (21519, 8255). Of course I do not expect the exact same accuracy, but SGDClassifier basically gets nothing right...

**EDIT**

I just found the reason - although I do not understand why there is SUCH a difference: I had an `amount` feature which includes numbers (= currency amount). With it included, the SGDClassifier performs horrible (= 0.3%), when transforming it to positive/negative, I get around 90% accuracy.

Comment: Try to normalize your features (X_train and X_test) before fiting/predicting with the SGDClassifier